# footer height in css

Tags: css, footer

I have an issue with a footer defined with this css:

```
div#footer {
    height:80px;
    background-color:#f2f2f2;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:999;
    border-top: solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

In firefox it works fine like it should, so the footer goes on until the end of the page:
[image: firefox view]
 but in Chorme, when the page is very short, I get something like this: 
[image: chrome view]
but I want the red block to be grey too, as in Firefox.

Can I fix it without setting a fixed height for the footer? Thanks.

More code:

```
div#footer .main {
    width:986px;
    margin:0 auto;
    color:#999;
    font-size:11px;
}

body {
    background-color:#E0DDD2;
    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#1a1a1a;
    line-height:16px;
}

<body>
    <div id="footer">
        <div class="main">
          <cq:include path="footer" resourceType="where/components/iparsys"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Need more code, but it looks like you set the background-color on your body tag as red, and you have a wrapper around your page content with a white background. If that's the case, just change the body background-color to the same gray as the footer and that should do the trick.

Comment: by code he actually means markup, please post as much as you can of your html so that we can help you :)

Comment: try adding `position:relative` to `div#footer` CSS. `Left` and `bottom` aren't doing anything

Comment: updated with more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doctype declaration was missing.

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`